# CLLLocationManager and delivering location updates to different parts of the app

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, location, cllocationmanager

In my app, I have a background service and a view controller that needs location updates (not constantly). So, I thought it's better to have a singleton class to capture location updates and distribute them to different parts of my app rather than delegating in every object that needs location.

My location manager is a singleton class that sets up CLLocationManager, turns on location when something calls the location manager and asks for location. How this works is, it has a method "currentLocation" that accepts a closure as an argument. The locationManager stores closures passed to this method in an array. Whenever the method is called, locationManager turns on location updates and once it has a good enough location, it executes all the closures, passing the acquired location into them and clears the executionQueue.

I'm aware of the retain cycles and I'm careful with capture lists given in the closures. However, I'm getting a rare `thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed crash` while the closures are being executed. The last time I got this, logs complained about bad usage of "weak". I am using a weak referenced object (weak self) in the closure, but the rest of the closure is only executed if the weak reference actually holds a reference to an object (`if let self = self { ... }` )

I have a few questions

1. Is this bad design? Can I do this in a better way?
2. I know NSNotifications are also a viable way to send out data to different parts of the app. I wish to know if this is better or worse than my design and how.
3. When I want to send out continuous location updates to different objects, what is a good method? Like, adding an observer with a target and selector (this is objectiveC-ish)
4. I have another design in mind. My locationManager will have a method `addObserver` with an argument that is an object that implements a protocol to receive location updates. Is this a good design?

Comment: I would recommend using a Combine `Publisher`.

Comment: Publisher is an interesting design and I was unaware of it. Thank you. I can probably use it in my future projects, but this one needs compatibility with iOS 12 and 11.

Comment: You can use OpenCombine for older platforms, it's an open source implementation of the Combine API. And of course, there's RxSwift, which has been around for ages

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which is similar to notifications but I think is better, because you can have many "messages" and it is easier to keep clean. If ios 13+ is the target, you can definitely use Publisher though.

Create a protocol for your singleton

```
protocol YourLocationManagerDelegate: class {
    func didUpadteUserPosition()
}
```

The ": class" allow that the delegate object can be a weak reference.

in your singleton manager create a list of delegates

```
private var delegates: [YourLocationManagerDelegate?] = []
```

in your singleton manager, create a register and unregister method

```
func register(Delegate delegate: YourLocationManagerDelegate) {
    if delegates.contains(where: { (delegateToCheck) -> Bool in
        return delegateToCheck === delegate
    }) == false {
        self.delegates.append(delegate)
    }
}

func unregister(Delegate delegate: YourLocationManagerDelegate) {
    self.delegates.removeAll { (delegateToCheck) -> Bool in
        return delegateToCheck === delegate
    }
}
```

in your object, register with weak self

```
weak var this = self
UserLocationManager.shared.register(Delegate: this)
```

in your manager, when you get a new update, loop through the delegates and call update.

```
func locationUpdated() {
    for delegate in delegates {
        delegate?.didUpadteUserPosition()
    }
}
```

since the object registers as a weak reference, it doesn't retain when they deinit. In addition, you can unregister in those object's deinit but that is not a must.